# React js context returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to pass some data to all of my react components for that I have created a context called `GlobalContex` that wraps all the components. Now this `GlobalContex` takes data into its `prop` from `MainComponent`.

When I console.log this data inside `GlobalContext` I can see the data in the browser's console but when I consume this data in one of the `GlobalContext` child component and console, it returns undefined.

Here is my code

**MainComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from "./Header";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

import {
    Route,
    BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import UserIndex from "../user/UserIndex";
import TrackerIndex from "../tracker/TrackerIndex";
import AuthUserContextProvider from '../../contexts/AuthUserContext';
import GlobalContextProvider from "../../contexts/GlobalContext";

const MainComponent = (props) => {

    const global_data = JSON.parse(props.testProp);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div id="wrapper" className="menu-displayed">

                <GlobalContextProvider global_data={global_data}>

                    <div className="prd-container">

                        <Header/>

                        <div className="content">
                            <Route path="/users" component={UserIndex}/>
                            <Route path="/tracker" component={TrackerIndex}/>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <Sidebar/>

                </GlobalContextProvider>

            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

};

export default MainComponent
```

**GlobalContext.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export const GlobalContext = createContext();

const GlobalContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [context_global_data, setGlobalData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setGlobalData(props.global_data)
    },[])


    console.log(context_global_data);
    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{context_global_data}}>
            {props.children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default GlobalContextProvider
```

**Console From Global Context**

```
{auth_user: {…}, login_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login", logout_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout"}
auth_user: {id: 1, name: "Dust Value", email: "dustvalue@dustvalue.com", profile_pic: "dummy.jpg", email_verified_at: null, …}
login_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"
logout_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout"
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavLink, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import GlobalContext from "../../contexts/GlobalContext";


const Sidebar = (props) => {

    const global_data = useContext(GlobalContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(global_data);
    })


    return (
        <div>
             Sidebar
        </div>
    )
export default Sidebar
```

Comment: Why does your context take the data as a prop? Just create it inside the context, that's what a context is for.

Comment: Actually I am using Laravel with react and want auth user details available inside each component as soon as MainComponent is rendered. I can't get that data using api route so returning it inside controller along with view

Comment: try listen **global_data** in userEffect in Sidebar component like this `useEffect(() => { console.log(global_data);}, [global_data])`  here is demo you can see >>  [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-gagarin-ixvx9)

Comment: I tried that  but still, it returns undefined